# What is SCBroker port in Siebel?

Tags: port, default, siebel

What is SCBroker port in Siebel server?

i learned that default SCBroker port is 2321, how can i change this default port.

this SCBroker interfering my application so need help to change the SCBroker port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14004_01/books/SystAdm/SystAdm_SrvrInfAdm5.html):

> The Siebel Connection Broker (alias SCBroker) component is a background-mode server component that provides intraserver load balancing. By default, it is always enabled and online. At least one instance of SCBroker must be running on any Siebel Server hosting interactive components.

...

> SCBroker listens on a configurable, static port for new connection requests from the Web server or a third-party load balancer. The parameter, Static Port Number (alias PortNumber), defines the port that SCBroker monitors. The default value for this parameter is 2321.

So you can change mentioned "PortNumber" parameter using srvrmgr utility (Siebel Server Manager). Instructions how to use this utility are placed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14004_01/books/SystAdm/SystAdm_SrvrMgrCLI.html). In short, you should connect to your server with the following command:

```
srvrmgr /g your_gateway /e your_enterprise /s your_siebel_server /u sadmin /p password
```

Then to verify current value of PortNumber parameter:

```
srvrmgr> list param portnumber for comp scbroker show PA_VALUE
```

To change parameter execute:

```
srvrmgr> change parameter portnumber=12345 for component scbroker
```

Where "12345" is new SCBroker port number. After that you need to bounce the component (note that server will be unavailable for users during restart):

```
srvrmgr> shutdown systemcomps
srvrmgr> startup systemcomps
```

Comment: if this list param does not return a value - use
list advanced param portnumber...